# CM network connection icon is grey

Tags: wi-fi, cyanogenmod, networking

I'm using CM 10.2 nightlies on my S 3 (i9305, intl. w/ LTE).

However, even though I seem to be connected to a network - the status icon is greyed out.

What's even weirder: I can access the web, but not the Play Store, which just displays 'No connection' and 'try again'.

See:

[image: Screenshot]

but:

[image: Screenshot]

Notice the grey WiFi icon in the top right corner - it used to be blue!

How can I diagnose/fix this issue?

Comment: That's not "weirder". It would be really weird if you could connect any Google service when the icons are grayed :) See the question Peanut linked for details.

Comment: @Izzy Although you can sometimes do that, I've found on older versions of Android the behaviour could be be a bit odd when it comes to the colour, haven't noticed it on 4.3 yet.

Comment: When the wifi icon turns grey, that means you have lost connection to the internet. You can still be connected to the local network, but if your device is cut off from the internet, the icon will remain grey. As @Izzy said, it would be quite weird if you could connect to google services while the icon was grey

Comment: Not quite correct, @John: It means you've lost contact to Google's servers. You can think of it as kind of "error indicator from the Google Services Framework". As the OP states (and screenshots show), he can even browse SE. And I doubt he's sitting in SE's server room to have that as "local network" ;)

Comment: But I can access Google.com and use the Gmail application. And also it has nothing to do with my local network, which is connected to the Internet.

I think the linked question is completely different. He asks _what_ those icons are, and I'm asking how to fix it. Not to mention we're using completely different versions of Android.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Google play cache? Have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting to your network? I would also try a quick reboot before you try anything drastic

Comment: @John: Cleared cache. Rebooted. Updated OS. Still nothing. Could it be an issue with the drivers or something?

Comment: Probably not a driver issue, are you using a custom rom?

Comment: CM (CyanogenMod) is a custom ROM, yes. (Right? I mean, everything is a "custom ROM", since the carriers and OEMs all modify vanilla Android.)